# How do I create an executable file (build, test and run) of my java project?

Tags: java, maven

I have an existing Java project which uses Maven.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gojek</groupId>
    <artifactId>parking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.parking.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I want to create an executable file in Linux that can

- builds the code
- run tests/specs
- run the program

I am assuming I need to configure the `pom.xml` first and then the executable will execute the maven command.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: were you able to achieve it @abiieez ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - builds the code
> - run tests/specs

You can use the command line to create an executable jar as

```
mvn clean install
```

> - run the program

and then execute the main class as specified in the plugin configuration using the java command

```
java -jar target/parking.jar
```

---

As from the comments, if the need is to execute these commands consecutively, you can put then within a shell script say `run.sh` and then execute the script instead using-

```
sh run.sh
```

Comment: How can I execute a file that run them all ? So if the test fails, then there's no need to package and run the program.

Comment: @abiieez If the test fails, the first step mentioned in the answer would fail and not package the jar to be executable which is a sane enough behaviour. Also if you mean executing all of these in one go. You can put then into a bash script and execute that script from the project root directory.

Comment: Alright. However I am still looking for solution that executes a single file, e.g `./program argument1`. Upon execution, it does everyting from cleaning, installing and executing the file.

Comment: @abiieez I hope I am clear with the idea proposed in the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most IDE's have a Build option, other option is creating some kind of make file, maybe CMake or a little script (it depends on the complexity of your program I guess)